# Git CLI new project is not working successfully

Tags: git, github, version-control, command-line-interface

I have a new empty repo which took over the name of a previous repo (whose name I changed).

When I do something like this:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
```

I believe it is still tracking my previous repo's contents (i.e. all the things I had uploaded), which I don't want: I just want to start from scratch. How to do this?

Comment: `git init` is a safe operation and it will not overwrite your old objects. If you want to start from scratch just delete the `.git` folder and `git init` again.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Thank you!!!